# Newman test summary shown mid-collection run

Tags: report, command-line-interface, newman, postman-collection-runner

When running my collections in Newman, test summary is shown mid-run and carries on with the request. This is possible due to a large number of requests being in the collection, but I trimmed it down to the bare minimum.

My question is, can I somehow tell Newman to wait until the end of the collection run?

The code I use to drive collection is:

```
const newman = require('newman');
var async = require("async");

async.series([
 function(next) {
  newman.run({
   collection: require('../rules_splitted/agent.json'),
   environment: require('../env_dev.json'),
   reporters: 'cli',
   bail: false
  }, next);
}])
```

I searched [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newmanrunevents) and [Here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/api_testing_and_collection_runner/newman_intro) for answers and here as well, but only this I could find is CLI report options that are not related to waiting time

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO68u.png)
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yVvG.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i don't get why you use var async = require("async");
all the calls already synchronous and are conducted gradually.
During all my using of newman I've never seen test summary to be in the mid.
Try to remove this async and start it with provided command
newman run collection -env ... -time
and here will no be any second of you seeing the test summary in the mid

P.S I use it with TeamCity CI

Comment: I mainly use it to run collection parallelly. Found the code on this page a while back. https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/examples/parallel-collection-runs.js .Will try your suggestion and let you know how it went. Cheers!